# How can I enable UnAligned Access for ARM NEON in LLVM compiler?

Tags: xcode, llvm, memory-alignment, neon

What is the flag to enable unaligned memory access for ARM NEON in LLVM compiler.
I was testing my ARM NEON intrinsic program in Xcode. I am accessing data from unaligned memory:

```
char TempMemory[32] = {0};
char * pTempMem = TempMemory;
pTempMem += 7;
int32x2_t i32x2_value = vld1_lane_s32((int32_t const *) pTempMem, i32x2_offset, 0);
```

Equivalent assembly for the intrinsic should be `VLD1.32 {d0[0]}, [pTempMem]`, but the compiler align it to next multiple of 32 and access data.  Because of that, my program is not working fine.

So, How can I enable unaligned access in LLVM compiler?

Comment: I'd understand if the compiler emitted instructions with alignment hints set and the program simply took an alignment fault at runtime, but the compiler actually generating code to access a different address than the one specified sounds really odd. Can you add the code (and possibly the relevant disassembly) to the question to make it clearer what's actually happening here?

Comment: @Notlikethat  My code is  

'char TempMemory[32] = {0};    
char * pTempMem = TempMemory;          
pTempMem += 7;    
int32x2_t i32x2_value =  vld1_lane_s32((int32_t const *) pTempMem , i32x2_offset, 0);'

Equivalent assembly for the intrinsic should be 
VLD1.32 {d0[0]}, [pTempMem]

But the compiler generated assembly is
VLD1.32 {d0[0]}, [pTempMem:32]

Comment: Please [edit the question itself](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/31176671/edit), rather than put important details in comments. Especially in the case of code.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't actually a NEON problem, it's a C problem, and the issue is:

```
 vld1_lane_s32((int32_t const *) pTempMem , i32x2_offset, 0);
```

Casting a pointer is a message to the compiler saying "hey, I know this looks bad, but trust me, I really know what I'm doing". Converting a pointer to type A to a pointer to type B, if the pointer does not have suitable alignment for type B, gives undefined behaviour. Therefore the compiler is free to assume that the argument to `vld_1_lane_s32` is always 32-bit aligned because there's no valid way it couldn't be (and you've promised you know what you're doing), so it emits the instruction with the alignment hint.

Now, you *could* fiddle around with options in an attempt to get a different kind of undefined behaviour that matches what you want, but that's just bodging around the problem rather than fixing it. That the underlying NEON instruction set can support unaligned accesses doesn't affect the C language's definition of and restrictions around data alignment.

I'm not familiar with how clever LLVM is, so I'm not sure if simply omitting the pointer cast would work (technically, C permits converting `char *` to any other type of data pointer, so it *should* be able to sort out the alignment itself). Otherwise, the solution is to use an appropriate `vld*_u8` operation to load the data into the vector via the correct type, then cast that with `vreinterpret_s32_u8` once it's in the register.

Comment: In order to know when the compiler assumes higher alignment requirements on casts, use the warning flag `-Wcast-align`. See [GCC warning options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html).